# How to evaluate a string?

Tags: elixir

Suppose I have a string with Elixir code like this:

```
"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

Considering that I already know that it's a list in the string, What's the simple way to evaluate it and convert it to an actual Elixir list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Code.eval_string](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3)

```
Code.eval_string("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]")
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 27 seconds!

Comment: @Sheharyar: yeah, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`Code.eval_string/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3)

> **[eval_string(string, binding \\ [], opts \\ [])](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3)**
>
> Evaluates the contents given by string.

**Example:**

```
{result, _} = Code.eval_string("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]")
```

Comment: your answer is more complete, but I already used the first answer!

Comment: It's eval_string/3, isn't it?

Comment: its eval_string/2

Comment: Technically all `/1`, `/2` and `/3` are correct. When using default arguments, the method is exported with multiple arities.